# Square Bracket in JSON File

Tags: json

I use requests to download json files. However, there are square brackets ([]) enclosing the json elements. And these brackets prevent me from importing the json file into Postgresql (jsonb field). How can I remove the square brackets?
My codes to download the json file:

with open ("C:\DATA\outputfile.json", "a") as f:
json.dump(response,f)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Square brackets indicates that the data is an array. If there is more than 1 element, then this isn't as simple as removing the brackets. Please consult the provider of the JSON file if you do not understand how to process an array of items and was only expecting an individual record.

Comment: You are right. I need to contract the provider to get more information (and I need to learn more programming as well). Thank you for replying!

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL can't accept JSON array structures, to import you must first convert the file to *New Line Delimited JSON* (NDJSON).

If you are a developer or have access to scripting tools, then you can do this by deserializing the JSON and manually serializing it into a flat NDJSON file.

> If the post is updated with a language or scripting tag then I can provide a specific example if you need it.

There are online tools you can use like this one that can help: https://konbert.com/convert/json/to/ndjson

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I will try to use Konbert to do conversion. But is there a way that I can write a python code to remove the initial and the last square brackets before saving down to the json file? Again, I am grateful for your help!